# Mold on salami, is it safe?

Tags: food-safety, dry-aging, salami

I took a salami and removed the outer plastic packaging and hung it in my refrigerator to dry. After about a week it got white mold on it. Is this normal/safe? I know that real/fancy salami has molds rubbed on. This salami does not contain any bacteria or fungus (at least it’s not supposed to) ingredients are beef, water, salt, flavorings, sugar, potato starch, sodium phosphate, ascorbic acid, sodium nitrite  [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's one thing to buy salami which comes with its own built-in mold, but to let one develop some possibly different mold spontaneously in the fridge?  If nothing else the fridge would not provide the ventilation which I understand is an essential part of the process (that's why you hang them and don't pile them up on a shelf).

Worse, I see a seam on the casing, which implies that it's a plastic casing and not a natural one.  I would not eat something which grew on plastic..

Answer (score -2):

I have seen dozens of different size/shape sausages hanging in a gourmet deli at room temperature , all were mostly white with mold. However, I can't say I ate any.

Comment: Those are usually a different type of sausage/salami, and they usually have mold on it. This looks like a soft/moist/fresh type of salami that was bought without any mold, so not the same.